# Defining packages with interfaces on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, interface, package, protocols

I have more experience in languages like C# and Java so maybe I'm asking the wrong question, but I'm trying to define on Swift packages with an interface, so any package that implements that interface (or protocol) can replace it.
For example on the data access package I want to define an interface with the CRUD methods so if I change the DB with another type the rest of the code isn't affected.
If this possible? And if the answer is "yes", which is the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Protocols are the closest Swift equivalent of Interfaces.  They let you define the properties and methods of a thing (and even some default method implementations) without being the thing itself).

Comment: I will add that default for protocoles is done in protocole extension.

Comment: Great @Paulw11 ! And regarding the folders/groups structure there is a standard?
For example I remember that in C# they though me to create for example:
MyPackage
|____MyPackage.Interface
|              |_____AnInterface.cs
|____AnInterfaceImplementation.cs

Comment: All files in swift have a .swift extension. Swift Package Manager has a structure for packages but this isn't anything to do with the use of protocols

Comment: @Paulw11 My bad, I forgot about the format on the comments. What a meant to show you on the previous comment is that on C# I got [something like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vTlCLRHpdnGE6xOV0wvQQ6XXhxmJ711k/view?usp=sharing), where I have a package with the implementations (i.e. BusinessLogic) and another package with the interfaces that those implementations must use (i.e. BusinessLogic.Interface)

Comment: I don't believe that there is any convention on the folder structure in Swift beyond that of Swift Package Manager. Unlike, say, Java the folder structure is not reflected in namespace in Swift

Answer (score 0):

You can create two separate swift packages. One package that is just the protocol (Interface) and the other package that is the struct or class (Implementation) that conforms to the protocol. For example...

The Interface package

```
public protocol SomeInterface {
     func doSomething()
}
```

and the Implementation package

```
public struct SomeImplementation: SomeInterface {
     func doSomething() {
          //stuff happens here
     }
}
```

The Implementation package must have the Interface package as a dependency in the Package.swift file

```
 dependencies: [
    // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
    .package(url: "https://example.com/some-interface.git", from: "1.2.3"),
 ],
 targets: [
    // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
    // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
    .target(
        name: "SomeImplementation",
        dependencies: ["SomeInterface"]),
    .testTarget(
        name: "SomeImplementation Tests",
        dependencies: ["SomeImplementation"]),
 ]
```

Then you can inject implementations that conform to the protocol while only needing to add the protocol package to your module.

```
init(dependency: SomeInterface) {
     dependency.doSomething()
}
```

This way your implementation package can evolve with version updates, without having to update the modules in your project that depend on the interface, as long as the interface package doesn't have any breaking changes.